# array placement when user input another data

Tags: c

user input 10 data, after that, user input 1 number. and the program will print out the placement of where the number store in the array.

```
int main() {
  int arr[10];
  int data,num;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d ",i );
    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  }

  printf("Input data : " );
  scanf("%d",&data );

  for (int j = 0; j < arr[data]; j++) {
    if (data==arr[j]) {
      printf("Data %d found in array %d\n",data,arr[j] );
      break;
    }
    else {
      printf("Data not found in array\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just print `j` instead of `arr[j]`. `j` is index

Comment: where is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main() {
  int arr[10];
  int data, flag = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%d ",i );
    scanf("%d",arr[i]);
  }

  printf("Input data : " );
  scanf("%d",&data );

  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    if (data==arr[j]) {
      printf("Data %d found in array at %dth position\n",data,j);
      flag = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!flag){
    printf("data not found in the array\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```